# ASP.NET MVC debugging best practice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, database-connection

We currently make website debugging on a remote `sales_debug` database instead of the production remote `sales` one.

The problem is speed, using the remote database from the local machine is very slow. I was trying to install SQL Server Express and SSMS on my local Win 8.1 machine and found it so complicated. This is [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/) that made wondering if I was doing the right thing.

The questions are:

1. What is the best configuration to make website that uses a DB debugging? Maybe I should use a less invasive DB engine with the same content?
2. Is a local copy of the DB the way to go? Or there is a trick to speed up connections to remote server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a machine in same network of your? You can use as a local server.
Install SSMS in this your machine then, SqlServer Express in your local server.

Comment: No, obviously it isn't.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you can use some machine in same network that your.

Comment: Yes, we have one... I will make a test.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest, and also best practice for testing your app to a database is to mock it away for your tests.You can use techniques like dependency injection and inject a fake database that is local and fast into your controller constructor and that way the results of the test is consistent and it is blazingly fast.  Traditionally this is used for unit testing and other types of automated tests, but I don't see why you couldn't do this for manual tests as well.  The same benefits apply.

Comment: I would argue that if you are having speed problems this is the correct answer for debugging as well.  It provides a safe, fast, and consistent mock database that can be used to test/debug your application.

Comment: One more thing to add though...if your debug database is slow and it is a good representation of your production database is your production db slow as well?  If it is you should spend your time speeding up your db access for everyone.

Comment: No, because production code works on localhost, the SQL server installed on the web server. The problem arises when we do debugging on the same remote web server SQL database.

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that this is a pretty small scale site?

Comment: I don't think so, there are thousands of customers, orders and order details in it.